# how to display labelvalues in the bottom axis in a Box-and-whiskers

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, teechart

I'd like to display the labels of serie, I mean the 7th argument of Box-and-whiskers.addxy(...) below the X bottomaxis and not as marks on the top or middle the boxes.
I tried palying with markpositions and marks parameters but the labels keep near the boxes and far from th bottomaxis

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to have the series label below the axis, just a replacement of the normal axis labels?